# State flow is not collecting emitted items

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

Imagine following scenario:
I open Search View and `SearchViewModel` is initialized

```
class SearchViewModel(
    usecase: Usecase
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            usecase.initialize()
        }

    }

    fun search(query: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        usecase.search(query)
    }
}
```

User start typing characters calling `search`

```
class UseCase(
   private val dataSource: DataSource
   private val store: Store
) {

    private val searchQueryEmitter = MutableStateFlow<String>("") // 2 change to MutableSharedFlow
    private val searchQuery = searchQueryEmitter
        .mapLatest { query -> dataSource.search(query) }
        .onEach { store.update(it) } 
        .launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)) // 1 comment

    suspend fun search(query: String) {
        searchQueryEmitter.emit(query)
    }

    override suspend fun initialize() {
//        searchQuery.launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)) // > Emit only initial value
//        searchQuery.collect() // > Emit only initial value
    }
}
```

Flow emits first item `""` and next items according to `query` value

**PROBLEM:**

1. I don't understand if we comment `launchIn` (1), and call it later in `initialize()` method, then exactly the same `searchQuery.launchIn(...)` or `searchQuery.collect()` cause issue - flow emits only first item `""`, but calling `search` with `query` doesn't trigger emission of next items.
2. If we change `StateFlow` to `SharedFlow` no items will be emitted in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `ViewModel`. I was using two different instances of `usecase`. The one passed in parameter was used in `init` while the second one came from `import`

so the desired case with

```
override suspend fun initialize() {
   searchQuery.collect() 
}
```

is working right now